# Finding pattern to extract text from a string using regular expession

Tags: python, regex, string

I have data which I'm reading in a string format as

```
>>> 26 24 16  Panelboards  10/05/18 26 26 00i  Power Distribution Units – Install  10/05/18
```

I want to seperate '26 24 16', 'Panelboards', 10/05/18  and '26 26 00i', 'Power Distribution Units – Install', 10/05/18 as *sub section, name, and date.*

Also after every date, new item can begin. In this case, after 10/05/18, new sub section begins.

I have used regular expression to filter out sub section as but it creates unstructuring in my data.

```
re.split(r'\d\d \d\d \d\d',sentence)
```

If anyone has solution to efficiently retrieve these 3 features for two items.

**Also, I can't use two spaces as regex due to change in structural file**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
\b(?P<subsection>\d+(?:\s+\d\w*)+)\s+(?P<name>.*?)\s+(?P<date>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2})\b
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e9SQNe/1/). *Details*:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?P<subsection>\d+(?:\s+\d\w*)+)` - Group "subsection": one or more digits and then one or more occurrences of one or more whitespaces followed with a digit and then zero or more word chars
- `\s+` - one or mor whitespaces
- `(?P<name>.*?)` - Group "name": zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s+` - one or mor whitespaces
- `(?P<date>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2})` - Group "date": one or two digits, `/`, one or two digits, `/`, two digits
- `\b` - word boundary

See a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/zErfEC):

```py
import re
pattern = r"\b(?P<subsection>\d+(?:\s+\d\w*)+)\s+(?P<name>.*?)\s+(?P<date>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2})\b"
text = "26 24 16  Panelboards  10/05/18 26 26 00i  Power Distribution Units – Install  10/05/18"
print([x.groupdict() for x in re.finditer(pattern, text)])
```

Output:

```py
[
 {'subsection': '26 24 16', 'name': 'Panelboards', 'date': '10/05/18'}, 
 {'subsection': '26 26 00i', 'name': 'Power Distribution Units – Install', 'date': '10/05/18'}
]
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you. However the regex demo link seems to be broken

Comment: @RaghavGupta Sorry, I have not figured out yet why the links get broken after copy/paste sometimes. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you. Also I love how I'm getting subsection, name and date from using P followed by a name but I'm a rookie in all of this. How could I get one more parameter namely section which includes just the first two numbers of subsection. For example, section for above both sub sections would be 26.

Comment: @RaghavGupta Not sure what output you expect then, try [this](https://ideone.com/wrFIWN) or [this](https://ideone.com/CqRaWI).

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
s = """26 24 16  Panelboards  10/05/18 26 26 00i  Power Distribution Units – Install  10/05/18"""

out = re.split(r"\s{2,}", s)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
['26 24 16', 'Panelboards', '10/05/18 26 26 00i', 'Power Distribution Units – Install', '10/05/18']
```

---

EDIT: If you want to split the 2nd item, use `str.split()` with `maxsplit=1`:

```py
from itertools import chain

s = """26 24 16  Panelboards  10/05/18 26 26 00i  Power Distribution Units – Install  10/05/18"""

out = re.split(r"\s{2,}", s)
out = list(chain(out[:2], out[2].split(maxsplit=1), out[3:]))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
['26 24 16', 'Panelboards', '10/05/18', '26 26 00i', 'Power Distribution Units – Install', '10/05/18']
```

Comment: `'10/05/18 26 26 00i'` needs to be split

Answer (score 0):

Be as specific as you can:

```
/^(\d\d \d\d \d\d) +(.+?) +(\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d)$/
```

Match group `1` for the subsection, `2` for the name and `3` for the date.

If you need to split the string first into each line, you could hook that into the end of the date:

```
\/\d\d\s
```